# How to add custom value to mysql fetch array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array fetched from mysql.

```
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
var_dump($array);
```

It returns the values as below:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'itemId' => string '4' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Ice Break' (length=9)
      'size' => string '500ml' (length=5)
      'supplier' => string 'Parmalat' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'itemId' => string '6' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Red bull' (length=9)
      'size' => string '250ml' (length=5)
      'supplier' => string 'Red Bull' (length=9)
```

Now, I want to add a customised key and value to this array so that the result is as below:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'itemId' => string '4' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Ice Break' (length=9)
      'size' => string '500ml' (length=5)
      'supplier' => string 'Parmalat' (length=8)
      'newName' => string 'Ice Break (500ml) (Parmalat)' (length=28)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'itemId' => string '6' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Red Bull' (length=8)
      'size' => string '250ml' (length=5)
      'supplier' => string 'Red Bull' (length=8)
      'newName' => string 'Red bull (250ml) (Red Bull)' (length=26)
```

I have tried this so far, but no luck:

```
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $array[] = $row;
        $array['newName'] = $row["name"].' ('.$row["size"].') ('.$row["supplier"].')';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Add it to `$row` and *then* append it to the array.

```
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $row['newName'] = $row["name"].' ('.$row["size"].') ('.$row["supplier"].')';
    $array[] = $row;
}
```